# How to use assertion to compare both different size of the rows?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng, assert

I want both size of the rows shouldn't be matched.

```
int firstnum = 0;
        List<WebElement> preRoutlList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='txBottomTable']/table/tbody/tr"));
        firstnum = firstnum + preRoutlList.size();


 int secondnum = 0;
        List<WebElement> aftRoutlList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='txBottomTable']/table/tbody/tr"));
        secondnum = secondnum + aftRoutlList.size();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare your these two variables then use this -

```
Assert.assertEquals(firstnum, secondnum);
```

In this line of code lets assume that `firstnum` is your actual value and `secondnum` is your expected value

Comment: You do not need to declare any variables and I think whats OP is asking is to check if they **don't** match.

Comment: Actually I was comparing both size shouldn't be match. I got the solution

 Assert.assertNotEquals(firstnum, secondnum, "Rows was not updated");

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different ways to achieve that depending on how you prefer to do things:

As another person has commented you don't appear to need those int declarations, so can just use the .size() call.

```
//Assert false that one equals the other
Assert.assertFalse(preRoutlList.size()==aftRoutlList.size());

//Assert True that one doesn't equal the other
Assert.assertTrue(preRoutlList.size()!=aftRoutlList.size());
```